# Transport winston logs to a server

Tags: node.js, express, winston

i was reading through the winston documentation and I came across the following statement

> A transport is essentially a storage device for your logs

So I assumed if i set up a http transport i would be able to aggregate the logs somewhere else. In my case in an application running in localhost:3210

Does anybody know why I'm not receiving the log I'm trying to send ?

Here is my code:

```
import { createLogger, format, transports } from 'winston';
const { combine, timestamp, label, printf} = format;

const myFormat = printf(({ level, message, label, timestamp }) => {
  return `${timestamp} [${label}] ${level}: ${message}`;
});

export const logger = createLogger({
  format: combine(label({ label: 'Test Service' }), timestamp(), myFormat),
  transports: [
    new transports.Http({
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3210,
      path: '/'
    })
  ]
});

logger.log({
  level: 'info',
  message: `Hello there`
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `logger.info('Hello there');`. Also, no idea how your server looks like, but make sure it has a defined `POST` method with the required path.